# Electron-tabs unexpectedly loads all tab sources into the same tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs, electron

I'm using [electron-tabs](https://github.com/brrd/electron-tabs) to build a tabbed view.

### Expectation

I expected to have exactly ONE html shown for each tab separately.

### Observation

However, running a modified demo program that comes with the package, contrary to my expectation, I found a single tab actually shows the contents from ALL tabs.

### CODE

Here is my `main.js`

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');

let mainWindow = null;

app.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Hello from Electron');
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            webviewTag: true
        }
    });

    // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

    mainWindow.webContents.loadFile('./app/index.html');

    // mainWindow events, within app lifecycle
    mainWindow.webContents.on('did-fail-load', function() {
        console.log("Failed to load index.html");
    })

})
```

The renderer.js

```js
const { remote, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
const TabGroup = require("electron-tabs");
const mainProc = remote.require('./main.js'); // plug in main process
const parser = new DOMParser();

let tabGroup = new TabGroup({
    newTab: {
        title: 'New Tab'
    }
});

tabGroup.addTab({
    title: 'Google',
    src: './tab1.html',
    closable: false
});

tabGroup.addTab({
    title: "Electron",
    src: './tab2.html',
    closable: false,
    active: true  // tab button is foregrounded
});
```

Here is the main page HTML: `index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
        default-src 'self';
        script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
        connect-src *">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>TabbedWindow</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- 2. Include the basic markup of the tabs view -->
    <div class="etabs-tabgroup">
        <div class="etabs-tabs"></div>
        <div class="etabs-buttons"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="etabs-views"></div>
    <!--
        3. Include initialization code, you can include another js file
        Or write directly the JS code here.
    -->
    <script>
        // You can also require other files to run in this process
        require('./renderer.js')
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here are the tab HTMLs: `tab1.html` and `tab2.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
        default-src 'self';
        script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
        connect-src *">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bookmarker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<!-- <body>
    <h1>Hello from Electron</h1>
</body>
<p>
    <button class="alert">Current Directory</button>
</p> -->
<h1>Bookmarker</h1>
<div class="error-message"></div>
<section class="add-new-link">
    <form class="new-link-form">
        <input type="url" class="new-link-url" placeholder="URL" size="100" required>
        <input type="submit" class="new-link-submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</section>
<section class="links"></section>
<section class="controls">
    <button class="clear-storage">Clear Storage</button>
</section>

</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
        default-src 'self';
        script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
        connect-src *">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>Cmdlet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<h1>Cmdlet</h1>
<div class="error-message"></div>
<section class="input-new-cmd">
    <form class="new-cmd-form">
        <input type="text" class="new-external-cmd" placeholder="whatever" size="100" required>
        <input type="submit" class="new-cmd-run" value="Run">
    </form>
</section>
<section class="results"></section>
<section class="controls">
    <button class="clear-results">Clear</button>
</section>

</html>
```

Here is how the loaded tab looks like:

I expect to see only `tab2.html`, titled "Cmdlet", under the Electron tab, but `tab1.html`, titled "Bookmarker", ends up showing up as well, which is wrong.

**Note that the original demo has the exact same problem.**

[image]

### UPDATE

I have security settings that cuased errors. After fixing my security with

```html
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
        default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
        script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
        connect-src *">
```

I've got rid of the extra content in the tab, but it seems that the loaded page blocks the tab buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Figured this out by myself.

#### Moral lesson: When in doubt, open Chrome DevTool.

This is a two-part fix.

## Part 1

The original problem is caused by a security violation to my HTML heads. The confusing visual observation is the result of renderer unable to finish drawing for the entire window and hanging in limbo. This security requirement seems to come from `electron-tabs`.

#### The fix

Add 'unsafe-inline' to all the HTML  like this

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
        default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
        script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
        connect-src *">
```

After that a real bug in the package surfaces.

### Part 2

After fixing the security, we get the view like this

[image]

This is caused by the rendered webview obscuring the entire tab view, which is a bug in current `electron-tab`, i.e., `0.11.0` at the moment.

#### The fix

The fix was given in [this issue](https://github.com/brrd/electron-tabs/issues/84) by [@ChandlerCPrice](https://github.com/ChandlerCPrice). It basically fixes the webview absolute positioning in the inline stylesheet.

Replace the original style injection code in `index.js` of `electron-tabs`

```js
// Inject styles
(function () {
    const styles = `
        webview {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            position: absolute;
            visibility: hidden;
        }
        webview.visible {
            visibility: visible;
        }
    `;
    let styleTag = document.createElement("style");
    styleTag.innerHTML = styles;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(styleTag);
})();
```

with

```js
// Inject styles
(function () {
    const styles = `
        webview {
            position: absolute;
            visibility: hidden;
        }
        webview.visible {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            visibility: visible;
        }
    `;
    let styleTag = document.createElement("style");
    styleTag.innerHTML = styles;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(styleTag);
})();
```

The tabbed view after applying the fix

[image]